# How to add a new line to MudTable with Inline-Edit

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

Can anyone suggest a method for creating a new record by using MudTable with Inline Editing?  Maybe clicking a new button and it creates a new line in the table to fill out?

Currently my MudTable references a List, when I click the Add button I created, it runs the following code.

```
public Publisher CreateNewPublisher()
{
    var newPublisher = new Publisher { IsNew = true, Editing = true };
    AdminPublishers.Add(newPublisher);
    OnChange.Invoke();
}
```

But the table doesn't show a new blank line.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I tried that in [this TryMudBlazor sample](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/mOwGkVaGKYDagXzz). I do not have your issue. Look it up. The table shows the new entry and I can edit it. `OnChange.Invoke()`  is not necessary. Please provide more details to allow us to identify the problem.